# PyQt5 missing methods on QJsonDocument / (QJsonObject)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to connect to a Scanner using PyQt5 over an REST API port. 
The Scanner/API uses Json Documents to connect and authenticate. However I have the problem creating a PyQt5 Json Document which holds the same information as the example C++ code.

The PyQt5 reference guide tells me that the QJsonObject is implemented as a "dict of str keys and QJsonValue values" [QJsonObject PyQt5 reference guide](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qjsonobject.html). When I try to insert these into a QJsonObject it is not inserted because the QJsonObject has no "setObject" method in PyQt5.

How can I be sure to send the same Message to the server as in C++?
Is there a workaround for this?

I have this example code in C++ I am trying to replace with python code (below):

```
QWebSocket socket;
QString address = …;
QString port = …;
connect(&socket,&QWebSocket::textMessageReceived,this,&Client::onTextMessageReceived);
socket.open(QUrl(QString("ws://%1:%2").arg(address).arg(port)));

void onTextMessageReceived(QString aMessage)
    {
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(aMessage.toUtf8());
    QJsonObject o = doc.object();
    if(o.contains("event")){
        QString type = o.value("event").toString();

        if(type == "authenticate"){
            QByteArray challenge = QByteArray::fromBase64( o.value("challenge").toString().toUtf8() );
            QString signature = \\signature here
            QJsonDocument d;
            QJsonObject response;
            response.insert("event", "authenticate");
            response.insert("response",signature);
            d.setObject(response);
           socket.sendTextMessage(d.toJson());
        }
        else if(type == "authenticated"){
            token = doc.object().value("token").toString();
        }
}
```

Python Code:

```
    self.client.textMessageReceived.connect(self.onTextmsgReceived)
    # connect websocket to port
    self.client.open(QUrl("ws://"+UDP_IP+":"+str(notificationsport)))


def onTextmsgReceived(self, message):
    # this method is to receive the challenge message from the scanner
    # it signs the challenge and authenicates with the agent/scanner
    print(type(message))
    print(message)
    if "event\": \"authenticate" in message:
        if "authenticated" in message:
            print("Autheticated!")

        json_challange = json.loads(message)
        challenge_str = json_challange["challenge"]
        signature = signmsg(challenge_str,priv_key)# sign challenge
        #signature_dict = {"response":QtCore.QJsonValue(signature.decode('utf8')),"event":QtCore.QJsonValue("authenticate")} # doesn't work - working with normal strings:
        signature_dict = {"response":signature.decode('utf8'),"event":"authenticate"}


        d = QtCore.QJsonDocument(signature_dict) # trying to inset dict directly        
        #d.setObject(signature_dict) # not working
        document = d.toJson()
        #self.client.sendTextMessage(document) # does not work  trying with str()
        self.client.sendTextMessage(str(document))
        print("Ready")



    elif "authenticated" in message:
        print("Autheticated!")
        #token =
```

Comment: Just use the `json` module (as you're aleady doing), and eliminate the redundant step of converting to a `QJsonDocument`. In fact, I can't see any reason for *ever* using the qt classes when working with json (unless another api specifically requires objects of a particular qt type). The python solution is much easier to work with. Assuming `client` is a `QWebSocket`, you can just do `sendTextMessage(json.dumps(signature_dict))`.

Comment: I used the json module and found some differences in the string I can solve with intend = 4 and seperator = ... . But I am still facing the same problem. I wrote an E-Mail to the scanner distributor so I hope the scanner doesn't need the specific QString class to connect.

Comment: What problem? The json format is defined by RFC 7493, and you are sending bytes via socket, not qt objects. Whitespace and separators are purely cosmetic, and have no relevance when parsing json.

Comment: I solved my Problem finally using the json module. The Trick is to use the right signature in the right encoding then it works.